# Upgrade AD FS 1.0 on Win 2008 R2 to 2.0

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, adfs

Since AD FS 2.0 is available for Windows 2008 R2, can i simply upgrade AD FS 1.0 to 2.0 just by installing AD FS 2.0 or uninstalling AD FS 1.0 then installing AD FS 2.0. Or is this too risky? I wonder if its better to install a new Windows Server (maybe 2012?) and then install AD FS or just upgrade it?

Answer (score 0):

You should see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678035(v=ws.10).aspx for migration details.

Note as Windows Server 2008 R2 is now in extended support phase there will be no more non-security related fixes. Only security fixes. So I'd recommend you move to Windows Server 2012 if you need AD FS 2.x specifically.

You will need to consider your current applications and review your applications to see whether you need AD FS 1.x style behaviour or whether you can change the apps to use Windows Identity Foundation and use WS-Federation. http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2010/06/23/ALL-WILL-BE-REVEALED-7-HOURS-RECORDINGS-FROM-THE-WIF-WORKSHOPS/ might help. Its a bit old but I suspect so are your apps.

Incidentally, if you decide to go with AD FS on Windows Server 2012 R2 instead future migrations will be easier to Windows Server 2016. See https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3871 for more details of whats coming and specifically on upgrade enhancements.

And some details of using the newer OWIN style to federate apps with AD FS.

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/